# DirectAccess DNS warning: Enterprise DNS servers (192.168.100.33,::1) used by DirectAccess clients for name resolution are not responding

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-access, direct-access

I'm attempting to set up DirectAccess Remote Access on a standalone Windows Server 2012 server (DC, DHCP, DNS etc.) are handled on another server.

I used the wizard but DNS kept throwing warning icons in the status viewer. I've tried setting it manually to the servers local IPv4 address, local IPv6 address, the domain controllers local IPv4 address, and also by deleting the entry and manually hitting Detect and then Verify (passed) but once saved the warning icon comes back with the same error message.

> Enterprise DNS servers (192.168.100.33,::1) used by DirectAccess
>   clients for name resolution are not responding. This might affect
>   DirectAccess client connectivity to corporate resources.

[image]

[image]

How do I sort it?

Comment: that box specifically asks for a v4 dns address.

Comment: `192.168.100.33`, not `192.168.100.33,::1`

Comment: add more details, server IPs for all servers v4 and v6.

Comment: AD and DA at the minimum

Comment: what's the v6 address of your domain controller

Comment: and the v4...v6 of your DA

Comment: oh,  sorry I missed that,  I never tried on the domain controller  I always used supported configurations

Comment: you could check your dns server listening addresses,  which could be one of your issues

Answer (score 2):

When adding the DNS server address here, the best way is to use "detect" as I describe here:

https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2015/09/22/directaccess-dns-not-working-properly/

You should NOT enter an IPv4 address of an internal DNS server or ::1, those are both incorrect. Also, DNS servers do not have to reside on member servers, they most certainly can be (and are commonly) installed on domain controllers.

Let me know if that doesn't work for you and I'll help you continue troubleshooting. There are a number of other things that can cause server responsiveness warnings in the Remote Access Management console.

Comment: The IPv6 IP address shown in the second screenshot was filled in using 'Detect'.